# Android Phone as a GSM Modem

Tags: c#, java, android, gsm, at-command

I would like my android to work as a GSM Modem, or by any other means, specifically, to send sms through it using some programming language library. What could be the way to do it programmatically as well as configurations/installations etc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610489/android-mobile-as-gsm-modem-to-send-recieve-sms-on-pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Learn how to send sms programatically

2) Learn how to write an android service

3) Learn how to talk to the local computer over wifi, bluetooth, adb port forward, etc so you can take commands

4) Be mindful of your carrier's terms of service - your "unlimited" plan probably does not let you use the device as a mass sms gateway.

In actuality, I think it's possible to send an sms from the adb command line by constructing an intent, in which case you could do it all with a script on the pc that pipes the right commands into adb - no development on the phone needed at all.

Comment: You should be able to find information on each step by doing a search for it in the developer docs and/or here