# Android mobile as GSM Modem to send/receive SMS on PC?

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, gsm

Is it possible to use an Android mobile device as a GSM modem with PC?

I am developing apps under .net to make send/reieve SMSs and so on. 
Now I'd like to connect my android devices via USB to my PC and use it as a GSM modem to communicate with it.

Here is the [Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325731/Bulk-SMS-Sender) site which I am following to create .NET application for this purpose.

and I am getting the error here

```
 try
 {
 Phone_Name.Text = comm.IdentifyDevice().Manufacturer.ToUpper().ToString();
 Phone_Model.Text = comm.IdentifyDevice().Model.ToUpper().ToString();
 Revision_Num.Text = comm.IdentifyDevice().Revision.ToUpper().ToString();
 Serial_Num.Text = comm.IdentifyDevice().SerialNumber.ToUpper().ToString();
 }
catch (Exception e50)
{
MessageBox.Show("Error Retriving COM Port Phone Information", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
```

It says "Error Retriving COM port Phone Information".

Is there any kind of driver/app/etc to handle it?

Environment: Windows XP/Windows 7 Mobile to test: Q Mobile Noir A-10

Answer (score 1):

If you are wishing to communicate using your phone, there are apps to install on your phone and connect it to your PC.

But if you are wishing to use GSM API to send instructions to your phone Arma's answer is correct but theoretically you can have a smart phone application to that takes the phone USB under control and emulates/imitates a GSM modem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can do it. Just install your cellphone drivers and then connect your mobile to PC. (Usually there are drivers in the mobile packages disks.)
Then open "Phone and Modem" from your windows control panel.
Then click on "Modems" tab. Now you can see all of your modems and their COM number.
Use you cellphones COM in your .Net application.
If you can not see you cellphones name as a modem in "Phone and Modem", it mean that you can not use you cellphone as a GSM modem.
(I'm sorry for my bad English speaking)